# Using Geocoding and creating the right locator in ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, geocoding

I have a set of addresses that I am wanting to geocode. I have available a parcel/points layer consisting of addresses in the region which includes the fields - street address number, road name and road type along with a full string of these in one field.

e.g. Address number - 12    Road name - Hunterway Road   Road type - Road     Full address - 12 Hunterway Road, Chartwell,                          Hamilton

I am hoping to use this layer above to create an address locator with the locator style - US Address - Single House.

USing this created locator I would like to geocode the address I have available which are currently in a CSV file format and have the following fields:

- Add1  -        12 Hunterway Road
- Add2     - Chartwell
- City_add - Hamilton
- Address_string - 12 Hunterway Road, Chartwell, Hamilton, 3210

Currently I am not getting this to work and was wondering if the created locator is the wrong type or whether I have to do some table edits with either the data used to create the address locator or with the data I am hoping to geocode.

Answer (score 0):

All sorted! There were formatting differences between the locator created and the data set requiring the geocoding. All of the fields used to create the address locator were integers/numbers for some weird reason so have adjusted and all working.